# Add more conversion units to existing apple classes of conversion

Tags: swift, measurement, nsmeasurement

Is it possible to add more conversion units to existing apple classes of conversion ?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/unittemperature 
On above link Rankine is not available. How to customize/extend this class and add Rankine ?

PS. Rankine sample formula is :
`5°C × 9/5 + 491.67 = 500.67°R`

PPS. planning to use it this way

```
let celsius = Measurement(value: 4, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
let kelvins = celsius.converted(to: UnitTemperature.kelvin)
print(kelvins)
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the documentation in [`Dimension`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dimension), which is the superclass of `UnitTemperature`.

`UnitTemperature`'s base unit is Kelvin. So I just had to look up the formula for converting Rankine to Kelvin, which is just a linear coefficient (`degreesKelvin = degressRakine * 5/9`), and plug that in:

```
extension UnitTemperature {
    static var rankine = UnitTemperature(
        symbol: "°R",
        converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 5/9)
    )
}

let celsius = Measurement(value: 5, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
let rankin = celsius.converted(to: .rankine)
print(rankin) // => 500.66999999999996 °R
```

Comment: hi, can you please add... what to do in case of non linear coefficients ?

Comment: Read the documentation. It's all I did.